# Does $\mathbb E[\varphi (x,Y)]|_{x=X}=\mathbb E[\varphi (X,Y)\mid X]$ always hold?

Tags: probability

I proved in an exercise that $$\mathbb E[\varphi (X,Y)\mid \mathcal G]=\mathbb E[\varphi (x,Y)]|_{x=X},$$
and thus, by unicity of the conditional expectation, $$\mathbb E[\varphi (X,Y)|\mathcal G]=\mathbb E[\varphi (X,Y)|X]=\mathbb E[\varphi (x,Y)]_{x=X}.$$

But I was wondering, does $$\mathbb E[\varphi (X,Y)|X]=\mathbb E[\varphi (x,Y)]_{x=X}$$
always hold or not ? I strongly suspect that no, but I can't find a counter example. Any idea ?

Comment: What does $\mathbb E[\varphi (x,Y)]_{x=X}$ mean?

Comment: It holds when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri : $$\int_\Omega \varphi (X(\omega ),Y(\omega '))\mathbb P(d\omega ')$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity holds for **independent** random variables $X$ and $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then it is in general wrong.

Take a square-integrable random variable $X \neq 0$ with mean zero and set $Y=X$, $\varphi(x,y)=xy$. Then

$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X,Y) \mid X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2 \mid X) = X^2.$$

On the other hand, $$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(x,Y)) = \mathbb{E}(x X) = x \mathbb{E}(X)=0$$

and so$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(x,Y)) \big|_{x=X} = 0.$$